# Why do /\w+:/ and /\S+:/ handle backtracking differently?

Tags: regex, pcre, backtracking

I analyzed these two regexes using [regex101](https://regex101.com/). I think the backtrack of `/\S+:/` is right. But I can't understand that difference. Am I wrong?

[image: regex101.com]

Comment: I'm actually curious how you got this to happen step-by-step so you could analyze it!

Comment: @Mehrdad: On regex101.com, enter a regex and use the `regex debugger` on the left side of the page.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While this appears to be implementation specific (RegexBuddy doesn't show this behavior), it can be explained as follows:

`\w` can't match `:`, but `\S` can. Therefore, `\S+:` needs to check more variations of the input string before making sure that `get` can't match it.

More optimized regex engines will exclude impossible matches faster (e. g., when the regex contains a literal character that isn't present in the current part of the match), but apparently the engine that regex101 is using isn't doing that.

Comment: I'm curious which regex engines are more optimized, and if there are any obvious distinguishing traits (besides the behavior you mentioned) - thanks!

Comment: I don't really know. I'm pretty sure that .NET, Perl and JGSoft's engines are very clever, but I don't know if there is a comparison available.

Comment: In any case, even clever engines, *will* fall into catastrophic backtracking in some circumstances, although they might avoid some instances that create problems for "naive" implementations.

Answer (score 15):

This is a [pcre](/questions/tagged/pcre) optimization called `auto-possessification`.

From http://pcre.org/pcre.txt:

> PCRE's  "auto-possessification" optimization usually applies to
>   character repeats at the end of a pattern (as well as internally). For
>   example, the pattern "`a\d+`" is compiled as if it were "`a\d++`" because
>   there is no point even considering the possibility of backtracking 
>   into  the repeated  digits.

and

> This is  an  optimization  that,  for example, turns `a+b` into `a++b` in
>   order to avoid backtracks into `a+` that can never be successful.

Since `:` is not included in `\w`, your pattern is interpretted as `\w++:` (the second `+` prevents backtracking, [see possessive quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html)). The extra backtracking states are avoided because there isn't another state where it could possibly match.

On the other hand, `:` is included in `\S`, so this optimization does not apply for the second case.

---

#### PCRETEST

You can see the difference using [`pcretest`](http://pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2test.html) (there's a Windows version you can download [here](http://www.rexegg.com/pcregrep-pcretest.html)).

The pattern `/\w+:/` takes **11 steps** and outputs:

```
/\w+:/
--->get accept:
 +0 ^               \w+
 +3 ^  ^            :
 +0  ^              \w+
 +3  ^ ^            :
 +0   ^             \w+
 +3   ^^            :
 +0    ^            \w+
 +0     ^           \w+
 +3     ^     ^     :
 +4     ^      ^    .*
 +6     ^      ^    
 0: accept:
```

However, if we use the control verb **[`(*NO_AUTO_POSSESS)`](http://pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2pattern.html#SEC2)**, which disables this optimization, the pattern `/(*NO_AUTO_POSSESS)\w+:/` takes **14 steps** and outputs:

```
/(*NO_AUTO_POSSESS)\w+:/
--->get accept:
+18 ^               \w+
+21 ^  ^            :
+21 ^ ^             :
+21 ^^              :
+18  ^              \w+
+21  ^ ^            :
+21  ^^             :
+18   ^             \w+
+21   ^^            :
+18    ^            \w+
+18     ^           \w+
+21     ^     ^     :
+22     ^      ^    .*
+24     ^      ^    
 0: accept:
```

<sup>- It takes 1 step less than `\S+`, as expected, because `\w+` does not match `:`.</sup>

---

<strike>Unfortunately [regex101](https://regex101.com/) does not support this verb.</strike>

**Update:** regex101 now supports this verb, here's the link to the 3 cases to compare:

1. `/\S+:/` (14 steps) - https://regex101.com/r/cw7hGh/1/debugger
2. `/\w+:/` (10 steps) - https://regex101.com/r/cw7hGh/2/debugger
3. `/(*NO_AUTO_POSSESS)\w+:/` (13 steps) - https://regex101.com/r/cw7hGh/3/debugger

regex101 debugger:

[image: regex101.com debugger]